# Addding a marker after fetching its lat and lng?

Tags: javascript, json, google-maps

i have been trying to fetch the Data of the ISS, to then add a marker on my map at its current location, i tried it like this

```
var map; // Globale Kartenvariable

function initMap(latitude, longitude) {
  // Erstelle eine neue Karte
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: { lat: latitude, lng: longitude },
    zoom: 18 // Ändere den Zoom-Wert nach Bedarf
  });

  // Füge einen Event Listener für das Klicken auf die Karte hinzu
  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function (event) {
    addMarker(event.latLng);
  });

  new google.maps.Marker({
    position: { lat: getIssLat(), lng:getIssLng() },
    map,
    title: "iss"
  })
}

const apiurl = 'https://api.wheretheiss.at/v1/satellites/25544';
    


async function getIssLat(){
  const response = await fetch(apiurl);
  const data = await response.json();
  const {latitude,longitude} = data;
  console.log(latitude);
  return (latitude);
}

async function getIssLng(){
  const response = await fetch(apiurl);
  const data = await response.json();
  const {latitude,longitude} = data;
  console.log(longitude);
  return (longitude);
}
```

and the Website terminal shows me that it gets the correct lat and lng(like this: 51.136557753762), but some how i get the following error:

js?key=...=initMap:138 InvalidValueError: setPosition: not a LatLng or LatLngLiteral: in property lat: not a number

some how it says that its not a number, does anyone of u know why this could be?

Comment: **Please remove your API key** from the question and then **revoke it** in the google api dashboard. [What to do if you accidentally publish your API key](https://sarakhandaker.medium.com/damage-control-ac15ecbd8468)

Comment: Now may you double check if `latitude` or `longitude` are strings? See [`typeof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof)

Comment: typeof says that its type is number, which makes it even weirder

Comment: `getIssLat` returns a promise, not a number. You have to add `async` to the `initMap` and then await `position: { lat: await getIssLat(), lng: awaitgetIssLng() }`. Also, making two requests is a very bad idea

Comment: that works, thank you very much, ill also change it to 1 request

Comment: now i would like to request data from an api with multiple objects, i want to turn the response.json(); into a json array so i may show multiple markers, how would i go about doing that?